# PNG overlay on a PNG image Imagick PHP

Tags: php, imagick

So I'm trying to overlay an image of a t-shirt(png), with a pattern(also png), with Imagick.

The code :

```
$img1 = new Imagick('test.PNG');
$img2 = new Imagick('pattern.png');

$img1->compositeImage( $img2, imagick::COMPOSITE_COPYOPACITY, 1, 1);

header('Content-type: image/png');
echo $img1;
```

When I run this code it does generate an image, but with the size of the pattern image (28x28). I want to "fill" the tshirt with my selected pattern, I'm fairly new to Imagick and I'm stuck on the image filling part. **I also made this for changing the color and that seems to work fine!**

Comment: Are you looking to change your dimension of 28x28 to a custom size ?

Comment: No, I want to repeat the 28x28 pattern in the t-shirt image till it fills the entire image (except for the transparent bg).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your code to

```
$img1->compositeImage( $img2, imagick::COMPOSITE_COPYOPACITY, 30, 30); // where 30 , 30 is the dimension of your tshirt.
```